# Can't get command line argument using sys.argv in python

Tags: python, sys

I try to pass command line argument to python script under win7, but the length of sys.argv always equals to one. Is that means it fails to recognize the argument? 
Here is the code and command line:

```
import sys
def Cat(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    for line in f:
        print(line)

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        Cat(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        print(input('enter argument: '))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is my command line:

```
F:\Google's_python_class\part1>Cat.py small.txt
```

But the result is

```
enter argument:
```

**SOLVED:**

There are two solutions:

1. `c:\...\python\python.exe Cat.py small.txt`
2. [solution two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540541/executable-python-script-not-take-sys-argv-in-windows)

Comment: See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626026/python-sys-argv-lists-and-indexes)

Comment: The file small.txt and python file is in the same folder, is that means I don't need to add the path?

Comment: Yes, In this case you don't need to add the path

Comment: What does `Cat.py` return? I am assuming an empty string. You don't need to specify the path if it exist in your [sys.path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897792/pythons-sys-path-value)

Comment: @ZhaoJ. no it has nothing to do with the path zhao, your example works fine here can you recheck the code that you have written in your editor. also do read the link mentioned by the other commentor it has some very detailed answer.

Comment: So what *is* in `sys.argv`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe would you please comment on Anderssons answer, if that is correct then i will be learning something new here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some people have reported this kind of issue [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue7936)

Can you try to launch it by calling the python executable directly ? This seems to fix the problem for some users.

```
C:\...\python.exe Cat.py small.txt
```

EDIT:

If python is properly configured, you can run :

```
python.exe Cat.py small.txt
```

Comment: then the OP should have the executable and the python code along with the file in the same folder...right?

Comment: Not necessary. All paths can be absolute if needed : `C:\...\python.exe F:\..\Cat.py small.txt`

Comment: But dont you think we should not make it too difficult for the OP to pass the abs path? if python is properly installed in the system then he can directly use the python filename.py command.
Your answer is correct but it would not be easy for the OP to understand and do, as you may see he is still in the learning phase.

Comment: So all the python file in my computer should add python.exe at first, right? Why some computer seems works well without python.exe at first?

Comment: @ZhaoJ. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540541/executable-python-script-not-take-sys-argv-in-windows) I believe that this is a problem in your configuration. But just to be sure, can you print `sys.argv` when not calling `python.exe` directly ?

Comment: I don't quite get it... Do you mean say `print(sys.argv)` in my code and call `cat.py small.txt` directly? If I do this, it will print me the path.

Comment: @ZhaoJ. Exactly, thanks. This is a good indication that your problem is similar to the one I mentionned above. The solution seems to be with the configuration of python

Comment: This question give me many other resource to learn today:) Thank you! Stack Overflow is amazing:D

Comment: @Patrick Yes you are right! Now I can pass the argument without add python.exe at first:D

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run your code with this command `Cat.py small.txt` then `sys.argv[0] = 'small.txt'` and there is no `sys.argv[1]`. Try `python Cat.py small.txt`. In that case `'Cat.py'` is your `sys.argv[0]` and `small.txt` is `sys.argv[1]`

Comment: The first element of sys.argv should always be the script name (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html)). I think it is a bug as this is not the expected behavior.

Comment: if you run in this way `python script_name.py` then yes, script name will always be the sys.argv[0], but if your system can recognize your script as executable programm then it's possible- it's not a bug

Comment: This is not what the python doc says. It says clearly : _argv[0] is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not)._. Maybe the OP can print `sys.argv` to see what is `sys.argv[0]` in his case.

Comment: but in our case `Python` is not an executable programm, so you can ignore python docs :) if you print `sys.argv` in code, after running `script.py 1 2 3` this will  output the list of `['1','2','3']` with no script name

Comment: @Andersson Are you sure ? Because to me this looks like [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540541/executable-python-script-not-take-sys-argv-in-windows) where the first argument is the script name, even when called directly without calling the python directly. The error looks similar and it was a configuration problem, not a feature.

Comment: Hmm.. It's weird:) I tried to run another script directly without running `python` and `sys.argv[0]` was a fullpath to script. Ok, I'll try to get deeper in this issue..

Comment: This method works!:) Thank you! But I am still comfused because the python docs seem not correct in my case.

Comment: @ZhaoJ. This method works but not for the given reasons ;) I think the python docs are correct and you have a configuration problem.